# Kiddush cup: stemmed or not?

Tags: kiddush, kiddush-cup

Is there any reason behind whether people use a stemmed kiddush cup or not? Does it have to do with minhag? Kabbalah?

I would have thought that some people who have a minhag to put their palm under the cup would used a cup without a stem, but I've seen people do this with a stemmed cup, which seems unsteady.

Comment: ive never heard of anyone using a stemmed kiddush cup

Comment: for example haGaon Rav Chaim Kanievsky shlita : http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/cbe.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was told by a prominent North American *posek* that stemmed cups are an American trend that was all but unheard of in Europe of old, especially considering the preferable orientation of one's palm under the cup for mystical reasons.

Comment: Do you have a source for said orientation's mystical reasons?

Comment: Aside from a lack of source, Rebbe Nachman of Breslov used a stemmed cup. As a matter of opinion, I find a stemmed cup to be very uncomfortable to hold in any position.

Comment: There is also the “Rizhiner _becher_”, with leaf-shaped attachments to the stem so it can be held in the kabbalistically-preferred manner; see [this picture](http://theantitzemach.blogspot.com/2010/12/sadigerrer-yohrtzeit.html#BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5550989448785690178).

Comment: @Seth i believe it is a Zohar but I don't know where exactly where he says when you hold it in this way, the fingers are pointing heavenwards as you make the brocha which has some deep kabbalisitic reasoning behind it

Answer (score 2):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe's (as well as his father's) cup didn't have a stem.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: There are pictures of both.

Comment: Could you link or upload photos of the bechers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it's all about some people who are very stringent to have there hand over the entire bottom of the cup and if you are holding a cup with a stem, the place where your fingers part for the stem of the cup isn't being held. Therefor you would either have to use a cup with out a stem or hold a stemmed cup from the bottom which can be pretty hard.

Comment: DYCbsa, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this answer! You could make the answer even more valuable by [edit]ing in whatever you can about where you may have heard this concept from. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.