# Any Reason for Kiddush Cup Plate

Tags: kiddush, kiddush-cup

Are there any Torah sources which encourage or discourage using plates for kiddush cups or a kos shel beracha?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8693/13811

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105521/759

Comment: perhaps related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43508/170